# How to get website use flash display in QT6 application using QWebEngineView

Tags: python, flash, pyside6, qt6

I want to build an app display flash website with pyside6

in the documentation of pyside6 it is mentioned:

Qt WebEngine supports loading Pepper Plugin API (PPAPI) plugins if WebEngineSettings::pluginsEnabled or QWebEngineSettings::PluginsEnabled is set.

The Pepper Flash player plugin can be loaded automatically if it is installed in one of the following locations, depending on the platform:
Windows
C:\Windows\SysWOW64\Macromed\Flash\pepflashplayer*.dll
C:\Windows\System32\Macromed\Flash\pepflashplayer*.dll

And I installed PPAPI flash 32 and had pepflashplayer*.dll files in SysWOW64\Macromed\Flash\ and System32\Macromed\Flash\ folders

But when i run my app, it's just a blank page

[link to image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pKOW0.png)

This is my code

```
from PySide6 import QtCore, QtWidgets, QtGui, QtWebEngineWidgets, QtWebEngineCore
import sys

app = QtWidgets.QApplication()

w = QtWidgets.QMainWindow()

central_widget = QtWidgets.QWidget()
w.setCentralWidget(central_widget)

view = QtWebEngineWidgets.QWebEngineView()
view.settings().PluginsEnabled = True
view.load(QtCore.QUrl("https://www.ultrasounds.com/US.html"))

lay = QtWidgets.QGridLayout(central_widget)
lay.addWidget(view)

w.show()
sys.exit(app.exec())
```

Thank for help.

Comment: TYPO: change `view.settings().PluginsEnabled = True`  to `view.settings().setAttribute(QWebEngineSettings.PluginsEnabled, True)`

Comment: Ohhh it's not a blank page anymore!! but the new problem is it shows "This plugin is not supported"
i'm installing pepflashplayer32, i've also tried installing lower versions of pepflashplayer but it still doesn't seem to work.